# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused error with GeckoDriver Firefox and Selenium on Raspberry Pi debian

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, raspberry-pi, geckodriver

I'm working on a Raspberry Pi and am trying to run a basic selenium script. Here's the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
d = webdriver.Firefox()
d.get("www.google.com")
```

What happens is that a firefox window opens, but doesn't respond. After about a minute I get this message:

```
 File "testy.py", line 3, in <module>
    d = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused
```

My geckodriver is in the path, and up to date. I've seen in previous posts that this can be due to an issue with the version of firefox. However I'm using the latest version I can install with apt (Mozilla Firefox 52.9.0). Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the protocol in the URL, such as 'http' or 'https':

```
d.get("http://www.google.com")
```

Comment: actually the exception traceback clearly indicates that the code execution didn't even reach the line with `d.get(...)`

Comment: @Bob Yes, I see that now. Missed it before. Well, now OP doesn't need to ask the 2nd question.

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
 File "testy.py", line 3, in <module>
    d = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
.
.
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused
```

...implies that the **GeckoDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Firefox Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- As *geckodriver is in the path and up to date* we are assuming *GeckoDriver* version as **0.24.0**.
- Your *Firefox* version is **52.9.0**.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *GeckoDriver v0.24.0* and the *Firefox Browser v52.9.0* as per the [supported platform matrix](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/geckodriver/Support.html) below:

[image: matrix]

---

### Solution

- Upgrade *Firefox* version to ***Firefox v65.0.1*** levels.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `Test` as a non-root user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

Without `http`/`https` it won't work

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'http://www.google.com/'
browser.get(url)
browser.maximize_window()
```